# How to convert Django app to RoR?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, django, ruby-on-rails-3

I just found out I can't deploy Django on cPanel so I'm converting it to Ruby on Rails. It's a small app where users can sign up for a bronze, silver or gold package for a service.

I precisely want to convert this flow from Django to RoR:

*DJANGO CODE:*

url:

```
#level is bronze, silver or gold
url(r'^signup/(?P<level>[\w\-]+)/$', views.signup, name="signup"),
```

view:

```
# subscribe to gold/silver/bronze package
def signup(request, level):
    """ when users subscribe to a package """
    context_dict = {}
    context_dict['level'] = level
    return render(request, 'payligent/signup.html', context_dict)
```

template on the index page that links to the signup page with the level (bronze in this case):

```
<a href=" {% url 'payligent:signup' 'bronze'%} "><button class="btn btn-success">Get Started</button></a>
```

*This is what I have so far for RoR:*

routes.rb:

```
get 'pricing/:level', :to => 'welcome2#pricing', as: "package_signup"
```

controller:

```
class Welcome2Controller < ApplicationController
  def pricing
    @package_signup = package_signup.find('bronze')
  end
end
```

view:

```
<a href="<%= link_to 'package_signup bronze', package_signup_path(@package_signup) %>"><button class="btn btn-success">Get Started</button></a>
```

However, I receive this error on the RoR server:

> No route matches {:action=>"pricing", :controller=>"welcome2",
>   :level=>nil} missing required keys: [:level]

Comment: In your controller, is `package_signup` a model?.

Comment: no, it's supposed to be a name for a URL similar to "signup" in the django URL: url(r'^signup/(?P<level>[\w\-]+)/$', views.signup, name="signup"),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="<%= link_to 'package_signup bronze', package_signup_path('bronze') %>"><button class="btn btn-success">Get Started</button></a>

get 'pricing/:level', :to => 'welcome2#pricing', as: "package_signup"
```

This route tells your app it's expecting a route path such as /pricing/bronze . So in order for the helper `package_signup_path` to work you need to provide it that last bit (`:level`).

Then on your controller you'll have the parameter `:level` dynamically set for you.

Meaning in your action you'll be able to access it - if you visit your app by going to `.../pricing/bronze` :

```
class Welcome2Controller < ApplicationController
  def pricing
    @package_signup = params[:level] # <- that will yield 'bronze' because rails translates that portion of the url that was entered and matched, to the name you gave it, you don't need to pass nor declare additional variables nor function parameters
  end
end
```

This now means your instance variable, that's usable on your views yields the value of 'bronze', or whatever was used to access this particular route. Meaning now your path helper will work as you have it.

The `<a>` tag will link you to the same page though, so not sure that's what you want?